# Jquery UI accordion: not understanding how to update content

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-accordion

I have a simple accordion with two section.  Upon clicking a button, I'd like to insert some text into the section that's currently activated.  My research keeps suggesting that I find the active pane using:

```
 var active = $(".selector").accordion("option", "active");
```

I know that .selector is a class but where does it come from and how come I don't see it in my Chrome debugger?  Why wouldn't $("#accordion").accordion be appropriate here instead?

Assuming that this is correct, how come I cannot simply append a

within the current pane?

```
active.append("<p>test</p>").accordion('destroy').accordion();
```

Full code:

```
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>jQuery UI Accordion - Default functionality</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://jqueryui.com/resources/demos/style.css">
    <script>

        $(function () {
            $("#accordion").accordion();
        });

        $(document).ready(function () {

            $("#addBeer").click(function () {
                var active = $(".selector").accordion("option", "active");
                active.append("<p>test</p>").accordion('destroy').accordion();

            });
        });
    </script>
</head>

<body>
    <div>

        <input id="addBeer" type="button" name="addBeer" value="Beer">
    </div>

    <div id="accordion">
        <h3>Section 1</h3>
        <div>
            <p>
                Paragraph 3
            </p>
            <ul>
                <li>List item one</li>
                <li>List item two</li>
                <li>List item three</li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <h3>Section 4</h3>
        <div>
            <p>
                Paragraph 4</p>

        </div>
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

A better way from what i wrote before.

EDITED

JSfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/fS6zT/

```
$( "#insert" ).click( function() { //inserts text to active panel
       var changetothis = $( "#something" ).val();

        n = $("#accordion h3").index($("#accordion h3.ui-state-active"));
         // alert(n); // test active number
        var section = n+1;
        $("#"+section).html(changetothis);
    });
```

In the fiddle there is a commented function which contains some extra elements usable for this, but they aren't needed. The uncommented function thats shown above is all you require.

Comment: hummm this doesn't seem to be working for me.  In your example, why does .selector change from a class to an object?

Comment: @user2077000 Hey, sorry i had no more time to fix. I have amended the answer with a working jsfiddle illustrating a better way to do it(imo). Let me know if you need any help with this.